# blackberry os 7 sencha touch tap text field

Tags: javascript, blackberry, sencha-touch

I just got a BlackBerry Torch 9810 running OS 7. I noticed my sencha touch app won't let me tap to enter a text input field. I have to click the trackpad. I know it works normally on non-sencha fields, like the ones here. I tried the example for forms from sencha and I'm having the same issue. I tried attaching a tap listener to the textfield but it's not being triggered. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sencha Touch 1 has many problems with Blackberry OS 7, I'd recommend upgrading to Sencha Touch 2 which has less issues. Yes, 'less'... there are still some.

In any case, I was able to fix this particular bug: https://gist.github.com/2645017

It's quite untested, so use at your own risk, but here's hoping it helps.

Comment: There's also a thread in the Sencha Touch forums on the same topic http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?148261-Sencha-fails-on-Blackberry-OS-7&p=799187